# Freeing memory of object

Tags: c#

I've got some code like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Someclass object= new Someclass();
    foreach (conditioin)
    {
        some methods();
    }

    object= null;
}
```

I need to free memory of object becuase every time that I press the button it shows me the same results. But methods inside should be forget and initialised with new result all over again.

Can you help me, please?

$$ UPDATE $$

OK so I'll provide the specific code

I use NativeWiFi

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();


        WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
        foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
        {
            Wlan.WlanBssEntry[] wlanBssEntries = wlanIface.GetNetworkBssList();
            foreach (Wlan.WlanBssEntry network in wlanBssEntries)
            {
                byte[] macAddr = network.dot11Bssid;
                string tMac = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < macAddr.Length; i++)
                {
                    tMac += macAddr[i].ToString("x2").PadLeft(2, '0').ToUpper();
                }



                listView1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}      Signal: {1}% ", (GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid)), network.linkQuality));

    /*
                Console.WriteLine("Signal: {0}%.", network.linkQuality);
                Console.WriteLine("BSS Type: {0}.", network.dot11BssType);
                Console.WriteLine("MAC: {0}.", tMac);

                Console.WriteLine("");*/
            }
        }

        client = null;

    }

    static string GetStringForSSID(Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid)
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength);
    }
```

Comment: You do not need to free the memory. What you do need is going through your code step by step and finding out where you go wrong.

Comment: Memory is freed by the garbage collector. There are other reasons of your unnecessary results.

Comment: You have to provide more detail about your code. What members does your class have, and what's happening in the constructor? Best is to boild down your code to a short example. That will often answer your own question before you actually ask it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common misunderstanding that setting a local variable to `null` frees up any memory. As the variable goes out of scope when leaving the method anyway, the `object = null;` line doesn't make any sense.

Also in .NET you can not force memory to be freed. The garbage collection does its job whenever it thinks it's time.

Answer (score 0):

Generally spoken, every time you execute the constructor `Someclass()` a new object is created. In plain C# the location in memory is irrelevant. All members will be initialized, either implicitly e.g. to null or by your own code. If you obtain the same results in each loop iteration that is because the initialization is the same as in the previous runs.